# Camel Velocity Template - access java object properties

Tags: apache-camel, velocity

I have a camel route which uses Velocity template and in the body I have an object defined as following:

```
class MailImpl extends AbstractMail{

    private BodyContext bodyContext;

    public BodyContext getBodyContext() {
        return bodyContext;
    }

    public void setBodyContext(BodyContext bodyContext) {
        this.bodyContext = bodyContext;
    }

    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MailImpl{" +
                "bodyContext=" + bodyContext +
                '}';
    }
}

class BodyContext{
    private String value;

    public BodyContext(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public BodyContext() {
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BodyContext{" +
                "value='" + value + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

In the velocity template I would like to access the MailImpl object properties, for example I use ${body.test} and ${body.bodyContext.value} but velocity template does not transform those values (it returns as string ${body.test} and ${body.bodyContext.value}).

One solution could be creating headers for each of of the value I need to use in the template, but as my route is dynamic (I select velocity template based on header) I would like to access the body properties in the velocity context. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a custom Velocity Context by setting the message header `"CamelVelocityContext"` (since Camel v2.14). From Camel's [test case](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-velocity/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/velocity/VelocityTest.java):

```
Map<String, Object> variableMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> headersMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
headersMap.put("name", "Willem");
variableMap.put("headers", headersMap);
variableMap.put("body", "Monday");
variableMap.put("exchange", exchange);
VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext(variableMap);
exchange.getIn().setHeader(VelocityConstants.VELOCITY_CONTEXT, velocityContext);
exchange.setProperty("item", "7");
```

With following template:

```
Dear ${headers.name}. You ordered item ${exchange.properties.item} on ${body}.
```

You get:

```
Dear Willem. You ordered item 7 on Monday.
```